# How to stop a Rigid Body link from automatically re-aligning

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I am simulating the action of a toy horse front right leg using Rigid Body Physics in Blender 3.2.2.  Once completing the full horse, the simulation will interact with other objects in the environment as it walks around.

The simulation is working well, but the last link (the horse hoof) is rotating to a new position when the simulation starts.  The hoof should not rotate to a new position.  The movement of the hoof should be controlled by the action of the link it is attached to.

Even at steady-state with no driving actions, the hoof link rotates to the undesired location.  See the [image: desired orientation] and the [image: undesired hoof rotation] below.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/13DPyouxNCXGhhiFNaK1yqtj4GJHoB0qd/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hWQxXox_vjOoDQ8DSsnL_bEjtNYEkpGW/view?usp=sharing

Here is the blend file https://drive.google.com/file/d/19hAv_MwNOwqg4qfhjCXZqH9-j93K4KZP/view?usp=sharing

UPDATE: 8/25 10AM

The toy horse leg functions as shown in this gif.https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DOZpdmkFS93WfzZCgsZt2-2OUMwXOmJn/view?usp=sharing

This image further explains the issue: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11jHJ20c9JI85BpasiC2-_y8MmZNsdPuw/view?usp=sharing

Here is a video explaining the error:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P17H1Z7WDRRJcUW68UbQIeeRx6igKdQA/view?usp=sharing

Here is an example of the mech. in Solidworks.  The motion should look similar to this:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vYDCoE3jZPb2Jc4rVCTCB45Z4zSieC9i/view?usp=sharing

Comment: maybe you should explain us how the movement should be and how your 7 hinges should work together....

Comment: Thanks Chris.  I've updated the original post to further explain the issue.

In short, there is a parallel mechanism joining the top and middle leg parts, this accounts for four joints.  Next, a cross-parallel link joins the middle and bottom leg parts, this accounts for four joints, but one of the joints is shared so it accounts for the remaining three.

Comment: Your rigid body objects start in collision.  Consider making a manual convex hull for each object (which can be done with GN's convex hull node) to see the intersecting hulls.  The rigid bodies are pushed out of collision on frame 1, which then transmits forces via the constraints to the hoof.

Comment: Good point.  However, I am not using the actual horse parts.  I am using very low complexity lines (edges) to create the hinge joints.  If I disable one of the conflicting hinge joints, the mechanism is smooth and the movement looks nice (not including the disabled joint).  I have removed any obvious collisions.  I will up date the original message with a desired motion demonstration using Solidworks.